# self written integration in matlab

Tags: integration

I'm really bad at matlab integration (approximation using my own code). Here I'm trying to implement the x,y,z components of an electric field due to a charged sphere. (see written equations below, where a, rhol (ps), epsilon are given to my function.)

[image]

However, the answer doesn't seem to be correct. This is what I'm doing, I'm sure there is something wrong.

```
function [Ex,Ey,Ez,V]=SphereOfCharge(x,y,z,N,rhol,R) %this is what you type to run. without "function" of course!

epsilon=8.854e-12;

dtheta=pi/N;
dphi=2*pi/(N+1);
theta=linspace(0,pi,N);
phi=linspace(dphi,2*pi,N);

for e=1:length(phi)
        for m=1:length(theta)
            dEx(m)=(4*pi*epsilon*rhol*(R^2)*sin(theta(m))*dtheta*dphi*(x-R*sin(theta(m))*cos(phi(e))) )/(((x^2+y^2+z^2)^0.5-R)^2)^1.5;
            dEy(m)=(4*pi*epsilon*rhol*(R^2)*sin(theta(m))*dtheta*dphi*(y-R*sin(theta(m))*sin(phi(e))) )/(((x^2+y^2+z^2)^0.5-R)^2)^1.5;
            dEz(m)=(4*pi*epsilon*rhol*(R^2)*sin(theta(m))*dtheta*dphi*(z-R*cos(theta(m))) )/(((x^2+y^2+z^2)^0.5-R)^2)^1.5;
            dV(m)=(4*pi*epsilon*rhol*(R^2)*sin(theta(m))*dtheta*dphi )/(((x^2+y^2+z^2)^0.5-R)^2)^0.5;
        end
        dEx2(e)=sum(dEx);
        dEy2(e)=sum(dEy);
        dEz2(e)=sum(dEz);
        dV2(e)=sum(dV);
end
Ex=sum(dEx2);
Ey=sum(dEy2);
Ez=sum(dEz2);
V=sum(dV2);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to integrate $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$ one easy variant is to rewrite it as a differential equation $y'(x)=f(x)$, $y(a)=0$ and use an ODE solver to find the integral value at $y(b)$.

Also, you should compute common subexpressions only once, here the denominator. That is what local variables in programming languages are for.